# Successor ordinal is preserved under addition

Tags: set-theory, ordinals

Is it true that if $a$ is an ordinal and $b$ a successor ordinal, then $a+b$ is a successor ordinal? If so, how does the proof go? It seems true to me, but I can't prove it.

Comment: What is your definition of ordinal addition? Under the definition I am familiar with, this is trivial.

Comment: If $b=c+1$, what can you say about $a+c$?

Comment: [This](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/759131/ordinal-addition-is-associative) may be useful

Comment: Ordinal addition is associative. So if b=c+1 then a+b=a+(c+1)=(a+c)+1.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Every well-order is isomorphic to a unique ordinal.

For ordinals $a,b$ the ordinal $a+b$ is defined as the ordinal that is isomorphic to the lexicographic (dictionary) order on $S=(\{0\}\times a)\cup (\{1\}\times b).$  If $b=c+1$ then $(1,c)$ is the largest member of $S$ , so $a+b$ has a largest member, so $a+b$ is a successor ordinal.

Intuitively, $a+b$ is formed by putting a copy of $b$ "after" $a$.