# Ordinal addition is associative - help with proof

Tags: set-theory

I'm trying to show that ordinal addition is associative, i.e. for ordinals $\alpha, \beta$ and $\gamma$ we have

$$(\alpha+\beta)+\gamma=\alpha+(\beta+\gamma)$$

My idea is to show that the identity map is a bijection between the set on the left and the one on the right. Then it will trivially be an order isomorphism and as every ordinal is order isomorphic to itself only, then the statement will follow.

The identity map is obviously injective, but I'm having troubles verifying that it is surjective. Also, as easy as this may seem, I can't show that this map is well-defined, that is that it maps the LHS to the RHS.

I had a look at this answer, but to no success - [Ordinal addition is associative](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/759131/ordinal-addition-is-associative)

Any help is appreciated!

Comment: How do you define addition here?

Comment: $1) \alpha+0=\alpha,  2) \alpha+\beta^+=(\alpha+\beta)^+$ and for $\lambda$ being a limit ordinal $3) \alpha+\gamma=\bigcup_{\beta<\gamma}(\alpha+\beta)$

Comment: Then it's basically by definition, use induction on $\gamma$.

Comment: Your approach, based on my answer in the linked question, is likely to fail since that hint is for a different definition of addition. And unless you have proved that the two definitions are equivalent, you will have a hard time using that approach.

Comment: @Berci: Yes, but when you have induction on three variables, it can get hairy. It's no surprise that people don't do it unless in dire need.

Answer (score 0):

This should be tagged elementary set-theory.

First show that your definition of ordinal sum is equivalent to the following: $\alpha + \beta$ is the lexicographic order on $\{0\} \times \alpha \cup \{1\} \times \beta$ (a copy of $\alpha$ followed by a copy of $\beta$). Now associativity is obvious.